# How can I plot a 3D graph of a multivariate integral function, and find its global minima

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, plotly

I have a cost function **f(r, Q),** which is obtained in the code below. The cost function **f(r, Q)** is a function of two variables **r and Q**. I want to plot the values of the cost function for all values of r and Q in the range given below and also find the global minimum value of **f(r, Q)**.

The range of r and Q are respectively :

**0 < r < 5000

5000 < Q < 15000**

The plot should be in r, Q and f(r,Q) axis.

Code for the cost function:

```
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

mean, std = 295, 250
l = 7
m = 30
p = 15
w = 7
K = 100
c = 5
h = 0.001  # per unit per  day


# defining Cumulative distribution function
def cdf(x):
    cdf_eqn = lambda t: (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((t - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
    cdf = quad(cdf_eqn, -np.inf, x)[0]
    return cdf


# defining Probability density function
def pdf(x):
    return (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((x - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))


# getting the equation in place
def G(r, Q):
    return K + c * Q \
           + w * (quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0] + quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]) \
           + p * (mean * l - r + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0])


def CL(r, Q):
    return (Q - r + mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
            - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
            + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / mean


def I(r, Q):
    return h * (Q + r - mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
                - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
                + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / 2


def f(params):
    r, Q = params
    TC = G(r, Q)/CL(r, Q) + I(r, Q)
    return TC
```

How to plot this function **f(r,Q)** in a 3D plot and also get the **global minima or minimas** and values of **r and Q** at that particular point.

Additionally, I already tried using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimise the cost function f(r, Q) but the problem I am facing is that, it outputs the results - almost same as the initial guess given in the parameters for optimize.minimize. Here is the code for minimizing the function:

```
initial_guess = [2500., 10000.]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, bounds=[(1, 5000), (5000, 15000)], tol=1e-3)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
      fun: 2712.7698818644253
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-0.01195986, -0.01273293])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     nfev: 6
      nit: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 2500.01209628, 10000.0127784 ])
```

The output `x: array([ 2500.01209628, 10000.0127784 ])` - Which I doubt is the real answer and also it is almost same as the initial guess provided. Am I doing anything wrong in minimizing or is there any other way to do it? So I want to plot the cost function and look around for myself.

It could be great if I can have an interactive plot to play around with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is concerned only with plotting but in the end I'll comment on the issue of minimax.

For what you need a 3D surface plot is, imho, overkill, I'll show you instead show the use of `contourf` and `contour` to have a good idea of what is going on with your function.

First, the code — key points:

- your code, as is, cannot be executed in a vector context, so I wrote an explicit loop to compute the values,
- due to Matplotib design, the x axis of matrix data is associated on columns, this has to be accounted for,
- the results of the `countour` and `contourf` must be saved because they are needed for the labels and the color bar, respectively,
- no labels or legends because I don't know what you are doing.

That said, here it is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp
from scipy.integrate import quad

mean, std = 295, 250
l, m, p = 7, 30, 15
w, K, c = 7, 100, 5
h = 0.001  # per unit per  day

# defining Cumulative distribution function
def cdf(x):
    cdf_eqn = lambda t: (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((t - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
    cdf = quad(cdf_eqn, -np.inf, x)[0]
    return cdf
# defining Probability density function
def pdf(x):
    return (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((x - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
# getting the equation in place
def G(r, Q):
    return K + c * Q \
           + w * (quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0] + quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]) \
           + p * (mean * l - r + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0])
def CL(r, Q):
    return (Q - r + mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
            - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
            + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / mean
def I(r, Q):
    return h * (Q + r - mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
                - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
                + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / 2
# pulling it all together
def f(r, Q):
    TC = G(r, Q)/CL(r, Q) + I(r, Q)
    return TC

nr, nQ = 6, 11
r = np.linspace(0, 5000, nr)
Q = np.linspace(5000, 15000, nQ)

z = np.zeros((nr, nQ)) # r ←→ y, Q ←→ x

for i, ir in enumerate(r):
    for j, jQ in enumerate(Q):
        z[i, j] = f(ir, jQ)
    print('%2d: '%i, ','.join('%8.3f'%v for v in z[i]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cf = plt.contourf(Q, r, z)
cc = plt.contour( Q, r, z, colors='k')
plt.clabel(cc)
plt.colorbar(cf, orientation='horizontal')
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

and here the results of its execution

```
$ python cost.py
 0:  4093.654,3661.777,3363.220,3120.073,2939.119,2794.255,2675.692,2576.880,2493.283,2426.111,2359.601
 1:  4072.865,3621.468,3315.193,3068.710,2887.306,2743.229,2626.065,2528.934,2447.123,2381.802,2316.991
 2:  4073.852,3622.443,3316.163,3069.679,2888.275,2744.198,2627.035,2529.905,2448.095,2382.775,2317.965
 3:  4015.328,3514.874,3191.722,2939.397,2758.876,2618.292,2505.746,2413.632,2336.870,2276.570,2216.304
 4:  3881.198,3290.628,2947.273,2694.213,2522.845,2394.095,2293.867,2213.651,2148.026,2098.173,2047.140
 5:  3616.675,2919.726,2581.890,2352.015,2208.814,2106.289,2029.319,1969.438,1921.555,1887.398,1849.850
$
```

[image]

I can add that global minimum and global maximum are in the corners, while there are two sub-horizontal lines of local minima (lower line) and local maxima (upper line) in the approximate regions *r* ≈ 1000 and *r* ≈ 2000.

Comment: Thanks for the plot. One thing I couldn't quite understand is and I will quote from your answer `while there are two sub-horizontal lines of local minima (lower line) and local maxima (upper line) in the approximate regions r ≈ 1000 and r ≈ 2000.` What do you mean by that? @gboffi

Comment: Additionally, I was wondering if there is a faster way to plot all the cost values (f(r,Q)) for the entire range of r from 0<r<5000 and Q from 5000<Q<15000. It could be great to see how at even at different points if it is able to reach a global minimum. Can this be built on a 3D contour plot with 3 axis? @gboffi

Comment: ① Maybe I shouldn't have said "local minima", what I meant is, there are a valley and a crest in your data and if you look at the print-out of values it's easy to see them (and please understand, I can point my finger at a feature but it's you that has to look and understand) ② A way to speed up the computations possibly exists, but it's not obvious — otoh the detail we've got with 66 points seems enough to start to reason on the characteristics of data ③ A 3D plot is easy (see n tutorials on Matplotlib site) but, I'll repeat myself, is not relevant here.